# how to compare case insensitive two strings in php

Tags: php

I need to compare two string case insensitive here is my code

```
if(strcasecmp($genderseek,"both")==0)
{
  $gender2="$Ugender=='MALE'||$Ugender=='FEMALE'";
}
else
{
  $gender2.="$genderseek==$Ugender";
}
```

this code n't working for me any one help me

thanks in advance

Comment: On my test machine the code you posted, works just fine. What error do you get?

Comment: Is it intentional that in the `TRUE` branch you just assign to the `$gender2` while in the `FALSE` branch you concatenate (ie `=` vs `.=`)?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in the first branch, your code should use `$gender2.=` instead of just `$gender2=`

Second, if this is building an SQL query, which it looks like, then you might want to use the SQL functions `LOWER` or `UPPER` to do the comparison with MALE and FEMALE, depending on your dataset

Third, again if this is SQL, `"$genderseek==$Ugender"` should read `"$Ugender==$genderseek"` since judging from your code, `$Ugender` holds the column name for gender whereas `$genderseek` is what the user is searching for?

Finally, you should really look into prepared statements. Your current code seems to be very vulnerable to SQL injections!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use PHP [strtolower()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function to compare everything at lower case. This way, case sensitivity will be eliminated.

Comment: [strcasecmp](http://php.net/manual/function.strcasecmp.php) allready compares without case sensitivity. I doubt this is the problem here. More like `$genderseek` issn't what @SureshKumar Vegesna expects it to be.