# how to convert compare two lowercase strings in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to compare case insensitive two strings in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813111/how-to-compare-case-insensitive-two-strings-in-php)

I need to compare two string here is my code

```
if(
    (strtolower($UgenderSeek)=="both")
    ? (strtolower($gender)=='male' || strtolower($gender)=='female')
    : strtolower($UgenderSeek)==strtolower($gender)
)
```

but it's working for any one me help me

Comment: Doctor I'm sick. Help me please

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve with the code. Put it in code blocks too, because now it is very hard to read and it doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: please point out how the question is different to your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813111/how-to-compare-case-insensitive-two-strings-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:
`$lowerGender=strtolower($gender);` `$lowerUgenderSeek=strtolower($UgenderSeek);`

> if(($lowerUgenderSeek=="both" && ($lowerGender=='male'||$lowerGender=='female')) || $lowerGender==$lowerUgenderSeek)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strtolower($UgenderSeek)=="both"){
    //do stuff
}else{
     if (strtolower($gender)=='male'){
         //do stuff
     }
     else{
          //do stuff
     }
}
```

your style would look like

```
$condition = true;

echo ($condition) ? 'is true' : 'is false';
```